# Не работает прозрачный фон у сцены

Tags: javascript, three.js

У меня возникла проблема, нужно сделать так чтобы под вращающейся 3d моделью не было фона(должен просвечивать остальной сайт, на фоне расположен градиент). Поискав на stackoverflow я нашел решение проблемы

> renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);

Однако фон сцены меняется на чёрный. Притом что цвет сцены я нигде не объявляю, только ставлю setClearColor через renderer. Если важно, то у меня есть 2 DirectionalLight, а сама 3d модель импортируется через OBJLoader2. Текстуру накладываю поверх, случайный jpg.
Вот то как выглядит у меня создание renderer'а, если поможет.

```js
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas}, {alpha: true});
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
```

Comment: `{canvas}, {alpha: true}` тут должно быть как-то так: `{canvas: canvas, alpha: true}`. Ибо у вас в конструктор рендерера передается два объекта параметров, а надо - один, в котором все необходимые параметры присутствуют.

Comment: @prisoner849 Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рад помочь :)